# Write a Boolean function that is given a binary tree and returns true if the tree has an even number of nodes

Tags: pointers, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, nodes

Q: Write a boolean function that is given a binary tree and returns true if and only if the
tree has an even number of nodes. An empty tree is considered to have an even number of nodes.

**Notes:**

The function should have just one argument, a pointer to the root.

No global variables may be used.

No additional functions may be defined. You may not count the number of nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes that a tree consisting of a single node is odd. That is, if your tree consists only of the root node, that tree has an odd number of nodes. It's not clear what "empty tree" means in your description. I assumed it to mean, "null root."

A node can be considered even if, combined, its children have an odd number of nodes. Yes, odd. Because you have to count the node itself. Consider the simple binary tree:

```
  1
2   3
```

Combined, the node's children have an even number of nodes. But you have to count the root node, too.

So one child must have an even number of nodes and the other must have an odd number of nodes.

Consider a larger tree:

```
       1
   2       3
 4   5       6
7
```

Node 4 is even. Node 5 is odd. Node 2 is even. Node 6 is odd. Node 3 is even. Node 1 is odd because both children are even.

The truth table, assuming even = true and odd = false:

```
left   right   result
false  false   false
false  true    true
true   false   true
true   true    false
```

So if both are true or both are false, then it's false. If either one is true, then the result is true. That's an exclusive-or.

This should work recursively. Let's try with the above tree.

- 7 has no nodes, so the result is odd.
- 4 has an odd left node and an even right node (a null node is considered even). 4 is even.
- 5 has no nodes, so it's odd.
- 2 is even because 4 is even and 5 is odd.
- 6 is odd because it has no children.
- 3 is even because left is even and right is odd.
- 1 is odd because its left and right nodes (2 and 3) are both even.

You should be able to write a recursive function given that description.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bool isEven(treepr *p)
{
    if(p)
    {
        if(isEven(p->left) == isEven(p->right))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could write that in a single line:  `return !p || (IsEven(p->left) ^ IsEven(p->right));`

Comment: Can you explain this, (IsEven(p->left) ^ IsEven(p->right)) ? 

I am not sure what exactly it do.

Comment: It's an [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). The result is false if both operands are true or both operands are false. The result is true only if one operand is true and the other is false. I showed the truth table for that in my answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JimMischel can you help me to solve this question. [Here is link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43379027/6939715)